# It is possible to exist more than 1 color code for same resistance. Can i use all of these color-codes?

Tags: resistors, symbol, colour-coding

It is possible to exist more than 1 color code for same resistance-value. I doubt, is there any convention about use only one of them (while manufacture) .

**Example :** Say an 1 ohm resistor could be expressed as Black-Brown-Black (01*10^0) simply, but when i buy  1 ohm resistors, i always found Brown-Black-Golden (10*10 ^(-1)) being sold.

[image: Example of more than one possible codes for same resistor]
**Example of more than one possible codes for same resistor**

Now, **i want to know, are the all possible codes correct?** or there are some conventions about it?

Comment: Non integer values won't work using a leading zero.

Comment: Now i got it. That means the manufacturer indicating in-this way, they're selling  1.0 Ohms , and not 1.1 or 1.2 or such. They're providing the significant-zero after the decimal point in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect this is done so that there are more significant figures available. For example, you can express a 1.2\$\Omega\$ resistor as Brown, Red, Gold, Gold

But it would not be possible to express this without the third Gold color band.

Answer (score 2):

The first digit is never a zero for standard resistors, so there is a unique code for each value.

Sometimes 0\$\Omega\$ resistors have a single black band.

Answer (score 2):

It's a form of scientific notation: -

[image]

If you only have two digits for "a" you cannot express (say) 2.2 with a leading zero. Consistency is the key word.